# gameObject transform position doesn't align with parent's transform position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am creating an inventory system, in which you can drag and drop items into slots. My problem is that when I drop my item into the slot, it doesn't align correctly.

I've tried using transform.localposition to set it correctly, but it changes absolutely nothing, they are still misaligned.

```
public void OnDrop(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        //If there's nothing already in this slot
        if(!item)
        {
            DragNDropController.itemBeingDragged.transform.SetParent(transform);

            DragNDropController.itemBeingDragged.transform.position = this.transform.position;
        }
    }
```

Here is the result : https://i.stack.imgur.com/qX9Wl.png
Note how the X/Y positions are -12.5/12.5. If I change it to 0/0 in the Rect Transform, then everything is aligned perfectly, but I can't seem to do it using code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably trying to set the localposition of the tranform, instead you should get the RectTransform and set its localposition.
Code:

```
RectTransform myRectTransform = GetComponent<RectTransform>();
myRectTransform.localPosition += Vector3.zero;
myRectTransform.anchoredPosition += Vector3.zero;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you set a transform as a child of another.
The child position no longer representing its own position,Let's just say it is the sum of all its parent positions + its local position.

So you made it a child of  a transform with position = 5,5,5.
but then you sat its position to be same as its parent which is 5,5,5.
Its total position is now 10,10,10.

You need to set its localPosition to 0,0,0, so its position is its parent position and wherever the slot goes, goes the item.

So to position it correctly at the center of the slot your code should be:

```
DragNDropController.itemBeingDragged.transform.SetParent(transform);

DragNDropController.itemBeingDragged.transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;
```